# Changing an array to a json with json_encode

Tags: php, json

I have this array:

```
Array
(
    [1] => 20130701 4 4 3060 1
    [2] => 20130702 270 757 13812810 4
    [3] => 20130703 5 123 3894971 2
    [4] => 20130704 290 478 5119617 1
    [5] => 20130705 88 98 189791 2
    [6] => 20130708 9 73 564627 1
    [7] => 20130722 6102 11992 41974701 1
    [8] => 20130723 6397 11021 40522224 1
    [9] => 20130725 4644 9336 49167728 2
    [10] => 20130726 4891 10157 33516844 3
    [11] => 20130727 123 319 2538226 3
    [12] => 20130728 451 801 1078705 2
    [13] => 20130729 13609 30407 95551827 5
    [14] => 20130730 6354 17550 272794650 158
    [15] => 20130731 6270 18456 269468599 174
)
```

I'm trying to change the output in order to show it in a chart, do i change it into a json:

```
foreach ($day as $key => $value) {
    $value = explode(" ", $value) ; 
    $day[$key] = $value ; 
    $charts[] = array(substr($value[0],0,4).'-'.substr($value[0],4,2).'-'.substr($value[0],6,2),$value[4]) ; 
}
$charts = json_encode($charts, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK) ;
```

But it displays me this :

```
[["2013-07-01","1\r"],["2013-07-02","4\r"],["2013-07-03","2\r"],["2013-07-04","1\r"],["2013-07-05","2\r"],["2013-07-08","1\r"],["2013-07-22","1\r"],["2013-07-23","1\r"],["2013-07-25","2\r"],["2013-07-26","3\r"],["2013-07-27","3\r"],["2013-07-28","2\r"],["2013-07-29","5\r"],["2013-07-30","158\r"],["2013-07-31","174\r"]]
```

why `\r` does show? any way I can prevent this ?

Comment: that's a carriage return char, and probably comes from wherever you got this data from initially. e.g. you need to `trim()` your array members.

Comment: Can you do a **`var_dump()`** rather than **`print_r`** of your array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
$charts[] = array(substr($value[0],0,4).'-'.substr($value[0],4,2).'-'.substr($value[0],6,2),substr($value[4],0, -1)) ;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have return characters at the end of your array

```
[3] => 20130703 5 123 3894971 2\r
```

They are not visible because `\n` = new line `\r` returns the pointer to the beginning of the line.

Your best bet is to use `trim()` on every element:

```
foreach ($day as $key => $value) {
    $value = explode(" ", trim($value)); 
    $day[$key] = trim($value) ; 
    $charts[] = array(trim(substr($value[0],0,4).'-'.substr($value[0],4,2).'-'.substr($value[0],6,2),$value[4])) ; 
}
```

It's even better on numbers to use `intval()`, which ensures datatype to be integer and removes blankspaces, returns, ... too.